# Android studio is not indenting the dart code

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, format

Could you help me with this please.

Android studio is not indenting my code asfter i save all my project.

This is an example:

`class DicePage extends StatelessWidget { @override Widget build(BuildContext context) { return Row( children: const [ Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),),), Expanded(child: Image(image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),),), ], ); } }`

Comment: can you recheck your dart & flutter plugin is installed or not

Comment: check if dartfmt is active to format on save

Comment: Hello, 
Dart & flutter plugin is properley installed
How can i check if dartfmt is active or not?

Comment: Ok, i found it, and it says "Code is formatted using the dart format tool included with the Dart SDK. See FAQ."